# A private repo on bitbucket still pubblicly clonable

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have created a "private" repo on bitbucket, but it seems to me it is not that private. If I do:

```
git clone https://myuname@bitbucket.org/myuname/myrepo.git
```

I get the repo without being prompted for passwords or anything like that. And I do not have an SSH key, as I hate them.

So the question is: What am I doing wrong? I am puzzled.

Thanks

Comment: Just tried it. Permission denied. It prompts for username name and password... are you sure you don't have saved it somehow in git ?

Comment: good question. How though? I even tried to apt-get remove --purge git and re install it. I need to try from another computer

Comment: I don't think so. Try to find some configuration files like .git and .gitconfig or just create a new user and try from there.

Comment: [This may be relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5343068/827263)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to delete the folder:

`.git-credential-cache` in `home/`

It is now asking for password again when cloning

Ta